# Alternative way for kotlin static methods

Tags: kotlin, static-methods

Im kinda new to Kotlin and I was wondering how I could make a static method.

```kotlin
Test.foo() //I want to do this from somewhere else in the program

open class Test() {
    
    private giorgor: String? = null
    
    fun foo(value:String) {
        giorgor = value
    }
}
```

I need to change the value of giorgor from somewhere else in the code and I thought I could use a static method to do that but I dont know how. Test also needs to be an open class

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do this is by making the **class** `open` or `abstract` and adding this

```kotlin
companion object Default: Test()
```

This makes it act like every method of Test() is inside the companion object Default.
If you wanted, you could also override an open method and make it have a different output for when it is used statically:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    test.foo() //Output: "jiorgor"
    Test.foo() //Output: "static jiorgor"
}

public open class Test() {
    
    var giorgor: String = "jiorgor"
    
    open fun foo() = println(giorgor)
    companion object Default : Test() {
        override fun foo() = println("static jiorgor")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a static method in Kotlin is a method in the companion object, e.g.:

```
class Test() {
    // …

    companion object {
        fun foo() = // …
    }
}
```

You can access it in the obvious way:

```
fun main() {
    Test.foo()
}
```

However, the bits of code I've elided make me suspect that this isn't exactly what you want: your example has `foo()` referring to a property of `Test` — and because each instance of `Test` has its own version of that property, it would need to refer to an specific instance. (And if you had an instance, there would be no need of the companion class — you could just make it a regular method of `Test`.)

In a comment, you refer to a Minecraft plug-in — can you explain what requirements that has?

BTW, a simpler alternative to the companion object is just a top-level method:

```
fun foo() = // …
```

From the same file, you can call it as `foo()`; from elsewhere, you'd call it as `<Filename>Kt.foo()` (since the compiler generates a dummy classname for top-level functions and properties, based on the filename). However, the same issues apply to that too.

Comment: In the plugin, all i need is to have other classes extend/implement (idk) this class like: class Blah(): Test() {}. but I also need Test() to have a static method that will be called from elsewhere like Test.foo() and foo will set the value of a private field that I cannot put inside the companion object. So I need an open class with a static method that has access to the class fields. If I don't make sense I could probably edit it in the post

Comment: Yes, if you can edit that information into the question, it'll help people who see it in future.

Comment: @user9277283 why can't you put the field in the companion object? That would make it a "static" property of the `Test` class. The code in your example is referencing an instance variable, which requires a particular instance of `Test` to access it on. You can't access that in a static way, because which instance of `Test` is it meant to be working with, and how does it get a reference to it? Or do you just want to get the "default" value it would be initialised to on an instance?

Comment: Well, now that you mention it, I could put everything in the companion object. Thanks

Comment: Made "some" edits to the question

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want an `object` instead of a `class`

```kotlin
object Test {
    var giorgor: String = "jiorgor"
    
    fun foo() = println(giorgor)
}

fun main() {
    Test.foo()
}
```

Comment: No. I was making a minecraft plugin and I wanted to be able to have other classes implement this one while also having a static method